# FCC certification for different products with the same antenna design

Tags: antenna, radio, fcc, radiation, certification

I was reading about FCC intentional radiation certification and am confused about a scenario. Let's say I have two products - Product A and product B.

Say I get FCC certification (for the wireless radio) for product A. Now can I use the same antenna for product B without going through the intentional radiation certification?

What is a good suggested approach in this scenario? I know one is to use a precertified module for the radio. Any other ways?

Comment: To an extent. There is no distinct boundary between "the antenna" and "things that are irrelevant for the radiation pattern", but there are a few shortcuts in the process that will make it easier to get certification -- otherwise having certified radio modules would be pointless.

Comment: No you can't. Absolutely not. It's not the antenna the produces spectral distortion into out of bound areas or, too much power (above limits); it's the electronics.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that you are asking about this:

Product A is some radio electronics *including* an antenna.
Product B is some other radio electronics *including* an antenna.

If so, it is irrelevant if the same antenna happens to be used in both products, they are still two different products and both need to be certified.

You could however design the products so that the RF parts are separated from the rest, and then you may be able to reason about the RF part being compliant since you haven't changed anything affecting it. This is a bit questionable still though, since things outside the RF electronics themselves may affect the radio characteristics, such as the RF supply and product encapsulation. For example changing some switching regulator and still claiming to be compliant would be highly questionable.

As for "pre-certified products" they will list a number of valid antenna reference designs and can be considered certified as long as the recommended antennas are used and you don't do anything which will have impact on radio or EMC characteristics. For example you can't go changing the TX power amp to some custom one in one product and still call it compliant.